# Use javascript variable as file name to download file with href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a javascript code that extracts filename as a variable from the current html file. The filename, for example, is "new.html" filename variable is successfully used to append href where I need to open same file strored in another folder. Using the same code, I need to append this variable to a folder path with href tag to download a file with href tag. The file name is extracted from .html (example new) and added to .xls file (example new.xls)

```js
var filename=location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
console.log(filename); 
document.getElementById("htag1").href= "Foldername/"+filename; 
var object=filename.slice(0,-5);
var xls=".xls";
var xlsfile=object+xls;
$(".xlsfile").text(xlsfile); 
console.log(xlsfile);
document.getElementById("d1tag1").href= "Foldername/"+xlsfile;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="htag1" target="_blank">#working</a>
<a href="#" id="d1tag1" target="_blank" download="">#not working</a>

<a href="Foldername/new.xls" target="_blank" download="new.xls">####working download code####</a>
```

But this is giving me download error with no file getting downloaded 
    but it is pointing to the right path. Should I use another way for download feature? Before this I had entered the file path statically which seemed to work. 
       Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What if the page isn't named as file?

Comment: Post a working snippet

Comment: It seems like you need to use absolute url, not relative as now. Try `document.getElementById("d1tag1").href= "/Foldername/"+xlsfile;`

Comment: What is the exact text of the download error?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno The page is named as a file so as long as the variable extraction goes, the code is working fine. It's only the download that doesn't work

Comment: @MysterX I tried but it didn't work :(

Comment: @JohnWu The error message says Failed-Network error (Google Chrome)\

Comment: can you post a working snippet?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I have posted the working version. Thank you!

Comment: it's not a snippet

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Is this okay? Sorry about not posting as a snippet before

Comment: There is a button called "JAVASCRIPT/HTML/CSS Snippet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, i'm sure now it will work ^^

```js
var filename=location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
console.log(filename); 
document.getElementById("htag1").href= "Foldername/"+filename; 
var object=filename.split(".")[0];
var xls=".xls";
var xlsfile=object+xls;
$(".xlsfile").text(xlsfile); 
console.log(xlsfile);
document.getElementById("d1tag1").href= "Foldername/"+xlsfile;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="htag1" target="_blank">#working</a>
<a href="#" id="d1tag1" target="_blank" download="">#not working</a>

<a href="Foldername/new.xls" target="_blank" download="new.xls">####working download code####</a>
```